# Enable/Disable a specific dynamically-added form-input

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, onchange

I'm creating an HTML form, which takes some of its options from a database (php + mysql)

In the php, I'm creating a `checkbox` input, with a select box next to it.

I named the checkbox `houseAppsSelected[]` and the select `customCategories[]`, so I'll get the values as an array.

I append all the HTML into a var called `$options`, and I echo it later on.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $cat_id=$row["category_id"]; 
    $cat_name=$row["category_name"]; 
    $options.="<INPUT type=\"checkbox\" name=\"houseAppsSelected[]\" VALUE=\"$cat_id\">".$cat_name." ---> ";


    $custom_sql="SELECT custom_cat_id, cat_name FROM custom_categories WHERE house_app='$cat_id'"; 
    $custom_result=mysql_query($custom_sql);

    $options.="<SELECT name=\"customCategories[]\">";
    $options.="<OPTION value=\"0\"> Choose Category </option>";

    while ($custom_row=mysql_fetch_array($custom_result)) {
        $custom_id = $custom_row['custom_cat_id'];
        $custom_name = $custom_row['cat_name'];
        $options.="<OPTION value=\"$custom_id\">".$custom_name."</option>";
    }

    $options.="</SELECT> <br /> <br />";
}
```

I want to have the checkbox control whether the select box is enabled or disabled.

I found [this article](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldisable.htm), which makes it look easy, but if all the select boxes have the same name, it will disable all of them.

Is there a way to have a specific checkbox disable/enable only a specific select box, if I build them dynamically with php? (they all have the same name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nextSibling` property to find the select.

```
function chkboxClick(chkbox) {
    chkbox.nextSibling.nextSibling.disabled = !chkbox.checked;
}
```

Add the click handler like this:

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" onclick="chkboxClick(this)" ... />
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/vAK7N/

Answer (score 1):

You can give each tag a unique "id" value, which is independent of the "name".  Then you can use

```
var elem = document.getElementById(something);
```

to access them by that unique value.

Exactly how your php code makes up the unique values sort-of depends on what you need, exactly. It can really be anything.

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good way indeed, but I decided to implement gilly3's suggestion, since it works perfectly with my layout of inputs.

Comment: Yes, that'll work, but if you have to go in and add another `<span>` or `<img>` or something later on, don't forget to update the code to deal with the new siblings!